# obj c, 5 colors, array, use them over and over again in a tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode4.5, modulus

I would like to be able to create an array with e.g 4 colors. And then use them in my tableview cells, inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. Like this:

```
-----------------
|      red      |
-----------------
-----------------
|      blue     |
-----------------
-----------------
|     yellow    |
-----------------
-----------------
|     green     |
-----------------
-----------------
|      red      |
-----------------
-----------------
|      blue     |
-----------------
-----------------
|     yellow    |
-----------------
-----------------
|     green     |
-----------------
```

And so on. I was able to do this with modulus in javascript, but in xcode/obj c I just can't figure it out. I looked everywhere. I managed to change every second, or just total random colors.

Comment: It should be as easy as adding a condition for each `indexPath.row`, but we need to see some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may do the following:

```
     if(indexPath.row %4 ==0)
     {
              cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     }
     else if(indexPath.row %4 ==1)
     {
              //setBackground to be the second color
     }
     else if(indexPath.row %4 ==2)
     {
              //setBackground to be the third color
     }
     else
     {
           //setBackground to be the fourth color
     }
```

this way each you will get the colors repeated each four rows, 
I hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank you. That wasn't that bad. My insomnia isn't helping me right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Modulus in C is the % operator, works just like in JavaScript. You could take the indexPath.row % number_of_colors to the the color index.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple just find the modulus of total number of colors which you wants to apply in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView`. Which solves your problem.
Still you are facing any problem then fell free to ask your problem again.